# How to delete child items of parent in treeview PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to delete the child items in a treeview, I have a dialog with a treeview, there is a data type column

[image]

When I double click on a datatype a dialog box pops up

[image]

and if the user changes the data type from List to something else I would like to delete the list from the tree.

[image]

As close as I can get is deleting the parent and the children with this

```
 self.model.removeRow(index.row(),index.parent())
```

I thought maybe I could iterate through with something like this

```
self.model.removeRow(index.row(),index.child(i)
```

But I am having trouble get the number of children to iterate over. Has anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove every children of a parent, you can use [`removeRows(row, count, parent=None)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#removeRows).

Since, just like `index()` and other functions, you can use a parent argument, you can get the children count of an item using [`rowCount(parent=None)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#rowCount).

In any case, if no parent argument is given, a `QtCore.QModelIndex()` argument is considered instead: a "blank" instance of [QModelIndex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html#QModelIndex) is considered as invalid, and it is also considered the same as the *root* index of a model as such.

**But**. If a *valid* parent is given, that will be used as a reference for the row and column parameters.

```
def removeChildren(self, index):
    self.model.removeRows(

        # remove as many rows as the row count of the *parent*, 
        # starting from row 0
        0, self.model.rowCount(index.parent()),

        # remove rows for the specified parent
        index.parent()

        )
```

I suggest you to carefully read and study not only the documentation about the class you're using, but also all the classes it inherits from (in this case, [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your advice the QAbstractItemModel documentation was very helpful I got the code to work I only had to make small change. Since the parent with the children was actually the sibling of the item being changed I had to use      self.model.removeRows(
                        0,
                        self.model.rowCount(index.sibling(index.row(),0)),
                        index.sibling(index.row(),0)
                    )